# No integer solution questions?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

> 1. Prove that $x^2-7y^2-24=0$ has no integer solutions.
> 2. Prove that $x^2+(x+1)^2+(x+2)^2=y^2$ has no integer solutions.

I am unsure of how to approach these problems? Are they modulo questions? Do I factor?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

2) $$y^2=3x^2+6x+5,$$
which says $$y^2\equiv2(\mod3),$$ which is impossible.

1) If so we have $$x^2\equiv3(\mod7).$$

Can you kill it now?

Comment: Where did 2(mod 3) come from? Because 5=2(mod 3) and 3 and 6 are 0 (mod 3)?

Comment: +1: Nice answer. I always forget to try something with the modulus :).

Comment: @Kelly R Because $3x^2+6x+5=3(x^2+2x+1)+2\equiv2(\mod3).$

Comment: Alright that makes much more sense. So for 1, it would follow that $x^2-7y^2-24\rightarrow x^2=7(y^2+3)+3\rightarrow x^2=3$(mod 7) and since there isn't anything in mod 7 that squared equals 3, there are no integer solutions.

Comment: @Kelly R Yes of course!

Comment: Prove $x^2 - 205 y^2 + 1 = 0$ has no integer solutions.